# Унаследовать class от HTMLElement

Tags: javascript

Код ниже в моём понимание присваивает переменной MyTimerProto ссылку на объект у которого есть свой метод tick и прототипом объекта является HTMLElement.prototype.

```js
  var MyTimerProto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);
  MyTimerProto.tick = function() { // свой метод tick
    this.innerHTML++;
```

Каким образом подобную структуру можно перенести в классовый синтаксис? Я пытался выстроить нечто подобное (код ниже), но получаю сообщение об ошибке.

```js
    class Test extends HTMLElement{
      constructor(){
        super();
        this.tick = function() { // свой метод tick
          this.innerHTML++;
        };
      }
    }
    
    var MyTimerProto = new Test();
```

Comment: Насколько я знаю (могу быть не прав, в этом случае прошу меня поправить) такой подход не используется, т.к. чреват различными проблемами. Насколько я понимаю Вы хотели бы создать некий счётчик. Если так, то почему нельзя создать класс, в который при инициализации передавать элемент/ссылку на элемент/Id элемента и далее работать с ним? Объясните пожалуйста цель.

Comment: @XelaNimed, я в процессе изучения учебника Кантора и там представлен следующий код для создания собственного элемента (https://codepen.io/barring/pen/PvREdO). Появилось желание сделать это в виде класса для в теории более удобного использования, но как видите, в ходе этого возникла проблемка)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Web_Components/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы были на правильном пути. Все, что вам осталось - добавить ваш класс в `customElements`.

```js
class Test extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log('constructor: Test')
  }
  tick() {
    console.log('method: tick');
    return 1;
  }
}
customElements.define('my-test', Test);

const test = new Test();
const test2 = document.createElement('my-test');
console.log(test.tick());
document.body.appendChild(test);
document.body.appendChild(test2);
```

Comment: Да, спасибо. Как раз только что прочитал это в документации, которую в комментариях подсказали и по аналогию к вашему ответу реализовал)